Mapping block attribute values from Mechanical Desktop .dwg to Solid Edge ST9 .dft
My company has a bunch of old drawings created in Mechanical Desktop 6 (.dwg file format) that we want to convert to Solid Edge ST9 draft files (.dft file format) using one of our templates. We're able to convert the drawings but are having issues with bringing in certain data in the format we want. Basically, we're trying to map the block in our Solid Edge template with the attribute values from the block in the .dwg. The values of the block are supposed to appear as a table containing the Revision #, ECN, Date of change, Initials of person who made the change, and brief description. See example from Mechanical Desktop below. The Attributes and their values are highlighted in yellow and the part circled in red is the table that gets populated by the attribute values.

Our problem is, after conversion, the block in our template remains blank unless we choose to bring in the block as a group (we're able to toggle this on and off in a config file). When we bring in the block as a group, the data does show up but as individual textboxes. It's easier for us to make changes by using a block in our draft file (see example below):

The blocks in both our .dwg and .dft template are named the same, so are the Attribute names. I tried adding the below statement into my config file but the target block in the draft file remains blank after converting.
[ImportAttributeValues]
EnableAttributeValueImport=1

[Blocks]
REVATTR = REVATTR

[Attributes]

REVL1 = REVL1
ECOL1 = ECOL1
DATL1 = DATL1
IN1 = IN1
DES1 = DES1
REVL2 = REVL2
ECOL2 = ECOL2
DATL2 - DATL2
IN2 = IN2
DES2 = DES2
REVL3 = REVL3
ECOL3 = ECOL3
DATL3 = DATL3
IN3 = IN3
DES3 = DES3

Does anyone have a good solution for this?
